# How to set laravel cronjobs in AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

How to set cronjobs for laravel app effectively without being affected when application run behind load balancers in AWS

Comment: so assuming you are running on ec2 machines ?

Comment: Yes am running on EC2 machine @Nishant Singh

Comment: so you straightforward use the cron demon on the ec2 instance (linux)

Comment: But when application runs behind load balancer cron job configurations vanish too @NishantSingh

Comment: I suppose the database is shared between the ec2 instance ? So you may use Laravel jobs instead no ? Then whatever the instance who run it, it'll be reflected in the database and the other server will not re-run it.